# Segmentation Fault after few realloc | Array of Structs

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, hashtable, realloc

Well, I'm implementing a hash table with array of struct form, like this:

```
    int SIZE = 769;
    int entries=0;


    typedef struct entry {
        long id;
        long n_article;
        long id_rev;
        long uni_rev;
    } Entry;

    typedef Entry * THash;


    THash init_THash ()
    {
        int i;
        THash  t = (THash) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(struct entry));
        //...
    return t;
}
```

I have a function that add something to the hash table and if the entries is more than 70% of the SIZE, I resize the table.

```
THash resize_THash (THash h){
    int i;
    int prime = SIZE*2;
    h = (THash) realloc (h,(prime)*sizeof(struct entry)); 
    //...
    SIZE = prime;
    return h;
}


void add_THash (THash h,long id, long idrevision){
    int i,r=0;
    if (entries > SIZE * 0.7) h=resize_THash(h);
    //...
    entries++;
}
```

The init of the hash table is correct, but the problem is when I realloc/resize 3 times, stops working, giving me segmentation fault; At this point I tried everything and I failed. Anyone can explain me, why this implementation is wrong?

For example: in this main, if the condition is `i<3000` it works, but if it's `i<6000`, doesnt work.

```
int main()
{
int i;
THash t = init_THash();


    for(int i=10;i<3000;i++){

       add_THash(t,i,627604899);


    }

    printf("SIZE:%d\n",SIZE);
    printf("ENTRIES: %d\n",entries);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `h=resize_THash(h)` : This can't update caller side(`t`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what is `t`?

Comment: please post an [mcve]

Comment: @xaxxon `t` of `add_THash(t,i,627604899);` at `main`

Comment: Also, did you actually malloc or calloc the original memory?  If not, that's going to be a sack of hammers.

Comment: @xaxxon I just edit and post a example of the problem. Thank you

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yes, I just edit the post, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_Thash` function doesn't return the new pointer, leaving the caller to use the old, now invalid, one.

Comment: It was this! Oh really! But why does it works few times ? It's strange. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Puthz When you cross the street without looking both ways, sometimes you make it to the other side -- but sometimes you don't.

Comment: Well, amazing answer xD I have been all day trying understand the error, thank you so much!